# How to process an array of results in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Here is my model.  I'm not sure I'm on the right track, but this is a start.  I have a survey form on my website and all of the values are numeric in INT fields.  I want to compute the average of each of 10 columns.  Rather than computing each result separately, I was wondering if there was a way to use a loop to process the results.  So here it is:

```
function survey_averages() {

        $q = array(
                    '1' => 'q1',
                    '2' => 'q2',
                    '3' => 'q3',
                    '4' => 'q4',
                    '5' => 'q5',
                    '6' => 'q6',
                    '7' => 'q7',
                    '8' => 'q8',
                    '9' => 'q9',
                    '10' => 'q10'
                    );


        for ($i=1; $i<11; $i++) {
            $this->db->select_avg($q[$i]);
            $query[$i] = $this->db->get('survey');
        }

        return $query;

    }
```

If I'm on the right track, then how to I get back the results of the array?  If I'm on the wrong track, what do I need to change?  Also, if I do this in my controller:

```
foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
```

How do I return the rows of my array?  PHP is not letting me do $row->1 or $row->'1'.

Comment: Not sure about the quality of queries themselves, but you should try to return a result from get() like this: `$query[$i] = $this->db->get('survey')->result();
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `var_dump($query->result_array())`

Comment: hi tpae, may be your suggestion don't work, $query is an _array_ of querys, not just one. look at $query[$i] = ...

Comment: @Carlos Mora: var_dump displays arrays as well. displays all information regarding that variable. http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Answer (score 0):

in place of

`$query[$i] = $this->db->get('survey');`

try

`$query[$i] = $this->db->get('survey')->result_array();`

then, to proccess the model's result you should do:

```
foreach( $query as $result )
   foreach( $result as $row ){
      // process $row
   }
```